# Why, as long as the if clause is established, the value is varied; a value is re-zeroed when it is out of the condition if in the python

Tags: python-3.x

I want every time that the object function is called, the value of s is added to a unit, but in this code, as soon as a unit is added, its value is reset to zero, and only as long as the condition is established its value becomes one and when it is exited its value is zero, while I want every time the if clause is set, add s to one, for example, 1, 2, and ..

```py
 def objects(x,y,startx,starty,startw,starth,objectw,action=None):
  s=0
  if y < starty + starth :
      if x <= startx + startw and x + objectw > startx + startw  or x + objectw == startx + startw or x + objectw >= startx and x<= startx or x > startx and x + objectw < startx + startw:
  s+ =1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but try defining your variable s outside the scope of the function. As it is now, every time you call your objects() function, it starts by redefining s to 0.

```
s = 0
def objects(x,y,startx,starty,startw,starth,objectw,action=None):
  if y < starty + starth :
      if x <= startx + startw and x + objectw > startx + startw  or x + objectw == startx + startw or x + objectw >= startx and x<= startx or x > startx and x + objectw < startx + startw:
  s+=1
```